# template member function resolution fails when declaring const

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, member

the code below shows some interesting behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class B{
public:
  void foo(B<T> &x)const;
  template<class F> void foo(F f);
};
template<typename T> void B<T>::foo(B<T> &x)const{cout<<"foo_B"<<endl;}
template<typename T> template<typename F> void B<T>::foo(F f){cout<<"foo_F"<<endl;}
int main(){
  B<int> a;
  B<int> b;
  b.foo(a);
  b.foo([](){;});
  return(0);
}
```

my expected output is

```
foo_B
foo_F
```

but the actual output is

```
foo_F
foo_F
```

it depends on whether `void foo(B<T> &x)` is declared `const`. If `const` is omitted the output is as expected.

Further, if `const` is added to `void foo(F f)` the output is as expected as well.

However, `void foo(B<T> &x)` will not change the `this`, whereas `void foo(F f)` will change `this`. So the current layout is the one required.

Any idea how to resolve this without dropping `const` is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that since `void foo(B<T> &x)const;` is const qualified, It would have to const qualify the object you are calling the function on.  This isn't as exactly as a match as `template<class F> void foo(F f);` provides as it doesn't need to do that const qualification.  That is why it is used for both calls.

You can fix this by also const qualifying the template version like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class B{
public:
  void foo(B<T> &x)const;
  template<class F> void foo(F f)const;
};
template<typename T> void B<T>::foo(B<T> &x)const{cout<<"foo_B"<<endl;}
template<typename T> template<typename F> void B<T>::foo(F f)const{cout<<"foo_F"<<endl;}
int main(){
  B<int> a;
  B<int> b;
  b.foo(a);
  b.foo([](){;});
  return(0);
}
```

Which will print

```
foo_B
foo_F
```

---

Another option would be to use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain the template version from excepting `B<T>`'s.  That would look like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class B{
public:
  void foo(B<T> &x)const;
  template<class F, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<B<T>, F>, bool> = true> 
  void foo(F f);
};
template<typename T> void B<T>::foo(B<T> &x)const{cout<<"foo_B"<<endl;}
template<typename T> template<class F, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<B<T>, F>, bool>>  
void B<T>::foo(F f){cout<<"foo_F"<<endl;}
int main(){
  B<int> a;
  B<int> b;
  b.foo(a);
  b.foo([](){;});
  return(0);
}
```

and has the same output as the first example.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responding. but the approach won't solve the problem as ```foo(F f)``` must be able change the object, which wouldn't be possible if declared ```const```.

Comment: @user1407220 I've updated the answer with a version that will allow that.

Comment: @user1407220 Just to highlight the difference between my approach, as they are subtle: this will invoke the `foo_F` overload for an argument of a different specialization of `B`, which may or may not be what the OP want. E.g. changing the type of `a` in the last example above to e.g. `B<double> a;` would invoke the `foo_F` overload for `b.foo(a);`.

Comment: @dfrib While true, if you did the same thing, your code would not compile as `void foo(B<T> &x)` is not a function template.  That's why I did it this way.  It's not clear exactly the behavior the OP wants.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes true.

Comment: Thanks. anyway ```void foo(B<T> &x)``` should make clear that the type of ```B``` will always be the same as that of ```this```.

Answer (score 2):

#### A qualification-conversion (here: on the implicit object parameter) is not an identity conversion, and has a cost in overload resolution ranking

The member function `void foo(B<T>& x) const` is `const`-qualified, whereas the template member function `template<class F> void foo(F f)` is not. This means the latter is a better match for a call where the implicit object parameter is *not* const, as per [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.rank#3.2.5):

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
> standard conversion sequence S2 if
>
> - [...], or, if not that, S1 and S2 differ only in their qualification conversion ([conv.qual]) and yield similar types T1 and T2,
>   respectively, where T1 can be converted to T2 by a qualification
>   conversion.

and [[over.match.best]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2.1)

If you `const`-qualify the automatic variable `b` in main, the non-template overload will be chosen:

```
// ^^^ `foo` overloads as in OP's example
B<int> a{};
B<int> const b{}
b.foo(a);  // foo_B
```

If you instead `const`-quality the template member function `foo`, then the non-template will be the same match as the template overload (const-qualification needed on implicit object parameter), in which case the non-template function is chosen as the best viable overload, as per [[over.match.best]/2.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.best#2.4).

---

#### If you never want a particular overload to participate in overload resolution for *type predicate*: remove it

> However, b cannot be declared const in the actual application, which boil down to making a copy, say const c(b); and then use c.foo(a)

You could use a trait to remove the template member function when the template argument for its type template parameter is a specialization of the `B` class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, template <class...> class Primary>
struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};
template <template <class...> class Primary, class... Args>
struct is_specialization_of<Primary<Args...>, Primary> : std::true_type {};
template <class T, template <class...> class Primary>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of_v{is_specialization_of<T, Primary>::value};

template <class T> class B {
public:
  void foo(B<T> &x) const { std::cout << "foo_B" << std::endl; }
  template <class F, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_specialization_of_v<F, B>>>
  void foo(F f) {
    std::cout << "foo_F" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  B<int> a;
  B<int> b;
  b.foo(a);
  b.foo([]() { ; });
  return (0);
}
```

where we've leveraged the `is_specialization_of` trait of [P2098R1](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2098r1.pdf) (just note that this has implementation variances for template arguments that are alias templates - somewhat underspecified IIRC).

Note that with this approach none of the overloads would be viable for an argument that is *another* specialization of `B` (than that of the implicit object parameter).

Comment: Hi. certainly an approach. However, ```b``` cannot be declared ```const``` in the actual application, which boil down to making a copy, say ```const c(b);``` and then use ```c.foo(a)```. Since both function may differ substantially in their body, forgetting the latter (that is using ```b.foo(a)``` instead) is a segfault guarantee. The better solution would be a structure where the compiler would raise a flag.

Comment: @user1407220 I expanded with a SFINAE-approach to remove the template overload for when the template argument to it is a specialization of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple even if a bit verbose way is to cast the object to const when you want to call the const version:

```
static_cast<const B<int>>(b).foo(a);
```

This is enough for the call to display `foo_B`...